# What does the 'maximum redirect' error in fetch-api means?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to fetch some data from a website but got the following error:

```
{ FetchError: maximum redirect reached at: <URL>
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\argentina\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1498:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  message:
   'maximum redirect reached at: <URL>',
  type: 'max-redirect' }
```

The code is:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const asyncFuncAsYouAsked = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        const myJson = await response.json();
        let data = JSON.stringify(myJson);
        fs.writeFileSync('data.json', data);
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("EROOOOR:");
        console.dir(e);
    } 
}
 asyncFuncAsYouAsked();
```

what does the 'maximum redirect reached at:' error means and what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: What happens if you open `URL` in the browser?

Comment: I am getting a JSON response.

Comment: Mmh. The error seems to indicate that the URL redirects to another URL, which redirects to another URL, etc. I would print out the HTTP headers you receive when making the connection.

Comment: @FelixKling I am trying to fetch https://forums.pubg.com/forum/7-game-discussion-feedback/page/2/ and in the browser it doesn't redirect but when using fetch it does. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the page you're requesting is redirecting to another page. Maybe you're requesting via the http protocol and it is redirecting to https, for example.

If not, perhaps you can still acquire the data you're trying to fetch by adjusting the `redirect` and `follow` [option-settings](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#options). Something like:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const asyncFuncAsYouAsked = async () => {
    try {
        let options = {};
        options.redirect = "follow";
        options.follow = 20;
        const response = await fetch(URL,options);
        const myJson = await response.json();
        let data = JSON.stringify(myJson);
        fs.writeFileSync('data.json', data);
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("EROOOOR:");
        console.dir(e);
    } 
}
 asyncFuncAsYouAsked();
```