# Maximum redirect when fetching URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, node-fetch

I am trying to fetch this URL "https://forums.pubg.com/forum/7-game-discussion-feedback/page/2/"

and I get this error:

```
maximum redirect reached at: https://forums.pubg.com/oauth/callback/?error=login_required&error_description=End-User%20authentication%20is%20required&state=12-aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3J1bXMucHViZy5jb20vcmVnaXN0ZXIvP2RvPW9wSWZyYW1lUmVmbG93UHJvY2Vzcw%3D%3D--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%3D%3D'
```

This is my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = "https://forums.pubg.com/forum/7-game-discussion-feedback/page/2/";
const response = await fetch(url, {
            redirect: 'follow', // this doesn't solve the problem
            follow: 10000       // this doesn't solve the problem
        });
```

I am not sure why because the URL doesn't redirect me in the browser or through postman. I guess this site has some kind of security in place.

Does anyone know why this happens and what I can do to solve it / bypass it?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what more I can add to this question, this is all the info I have. Could you please tell me what I can do to make this question better because I don't have more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be made better by adding the code that you are using that is causing the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706837/what-does-the-maximum-redirect-error-in-fetch-api-means

Comment: @ChrisHG Yes, I took a look at it before I asked this question, it doesn't solve the problem for me. I also have it only with this link.